# Grid inside responsive Container MUI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve something similar to what youtube does on its website, which is:

[image]
[image]

Basically, what YT (seems to do) does is to increase/decrease the grid count depending on the container size, based whether the Drawer is open/close.

Bottom line, my code does not reflect layout change (I suspect MUI listens to the window size instead of the parent size).
Is it possible to make it work?

Versions:

"@mui/material": "^5.15.0",
"next": "^14.0.4",
"react": "18.2.0",

Thanks

I've tried doing something similar using MUI + NextJS, but it's not working.

The relevant snippets:

```
import { Box, Container } from '@mui/material'
import Header from '../components/Layout/Header'
import { ServerAuthProvider } from '../../auth/server-auth-provider'

export default function Layout(props: {
    children: React.ReactNode,
    body: React.ReactNode,
    filters: React.ReactNode,
}) {
    return (
        <ServerAuthProvider>
            <Header maxWidth={false}>
                <Container maxWidth={false}>
                    <Box ml={2} mt={10}>
                        {props.filters}
                        {props.body}
                        {props.children}
                    </Box>
                </Container>
            </Header>
        </ServerAuthProvider>
    )
}
```

the body (relevant part)

```
<Box sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 2, ml: -1, mr: -1 }}>
            <Unstable_Grid2 container spacing={2}>
                {events?.map((event: EventSummary) => (
                    <Unstable_Grid2 xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={4} xl={3} xxl={12 / 5} key={event.id + event.starts_at}>
                        <EventCard event={event} />
                    </Unstable_Grid2>
                ))}
            </Unstable_Grid2 >
        </Box >
```

```
const drawerWidth = 240;

const openedMixin = (theme: Theme): CSSObject => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    border: 'none',
    borderWidth: 0,
});

const closedMixin = (theme: Theme): CSSObject => ({
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    border: 'none',
    borderWidth: 0,
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
    },
});

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
    ({ theme, open }) => ({
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        boxSizing: 'unset',
        ...(open && {
            ...openedMixin(theme),
            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
        }),
        ...(!open && {
            ...closedMixin(theme),
            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
        }),
    }),
);

const Main = styled('main', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })<{
    open?: boolean;
}>(({ theme, open }) => ({
    flexGrow: 1,
    // padding: theme.spacing(3),
    // transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
    //     easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    //     duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    // }),
    // width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    ...(open && {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
        marginLeft: 0,
        overflow: 'auto'
    }),
}));

export default function PrimaryHeader({ maxWidth, children }: { maxWidth?: false | undefined, children?: ReactNode }) {
    const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

    const { user } = useAuth();
    const { getFirebaseAuth } = useFirebaseAuth()
    const router = useRouter()

    const theme = useTheme()
    const isXl = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('xl'))
    const isMd = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md'))

    const logout = async () => {
        const auth = getFirebaseAuth()
        await signOut(auth)
        await fetch('/api/logout')
        window.location.reload()
    }

    const loggedOptions = [{ title: 'Logout', callback: logout }]
    const notLoggedOptions = [{ title: 'Entrar', callback: () => router.push('/login') }]
    return (
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar position="fixed" sx={{ bgcolor: 'white', zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1, }} elevation={0}>
                <Container disableGutters maxWidth={maxWidth}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        {!!children && <IconButton
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="open drawer"
                            onClick={() => { setOpen((prev) => !prev) }}
                            edge="start"
                            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
                        >
                            <MenuIcon sx={{ color: 'black' }} />
                        </IconButton>}
                    </Toolbar>
                </Container>
            </AppBar>
            {!!children && <>
                <Drawer
                    variant="permanent"
                    open={open}
                >
                    <DrawerHeader />
                    <List>
                        {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
                                <ListItemButton
                                    sx={{
                                        minHeight: 48,
                                        justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                                        px: 2.5,
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <ListItemIcon
                                        sx={{
                                            minWidth: 0,
                                            mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                                    </ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
                                </ListItemButton>
                            </ListItem>
                        ))}
                    </List>
                </Drawer>
                <Main open={open}><Container maxWidth={maxWidth}>{children}</Container></Main>
            </>}
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, breakpoints are based off viewport width, not current container width.

But what you are looking for can be achieved using basic CSS grid:

```js
const { useState } = React
const App = () => {
  const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div className={'App' + (isSidebarOpen ? ' sidebar-open' : '')}>
      <header className="header">Header</header>
      <div className="sidebar" onClick={() => setIsSidebarOpen(!isSidebarOpen)}>
        {isSidebarOpen ? '<' : '>'}
      </div>
      <main>
        {Array.from({ length: 24 }).map((_, key) => (
          <div className="box" key={key}>{key + 1}</div>
        ))}
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />)
```

```css
body { 
  margin: 0;
}
.App {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 'header header' auto 'sidebar main' 1fr / 3rem 1fr;
  transition: grid-template-columns .42s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}
.App.sidebar-open {
  grid-template-columns: 16rem 1fr;
}
.App > * {
  padding: 1rem;
}
header {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  grid-area: header;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  height: min-content;
}
.box {
  aspect-ratio: 1/0.7;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Click on the sidebar to toggle it.

The key is in

```css
main {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr))
}
```

... which tries to fit as many columns of `150px` as possible in the available width. Any extra width is then divided between columns equally.

Change `150px` to whatever makes sense for your case.
Everything else is not particularly relevant; I added it in to make the example look more like a *"layout"*.

---

If you don't want the columns to have variable width and you'd rather distribute the extra space on the sides, use:

```css
main {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
  justify-content: center;    
}
```

Demo:

```js
const { useState } = React
const App = () => {
  const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div className={'App' + (isSidebarOpen ? ' sidebar-open' : '')}>
      <header className="header">Header</header>
      <div className="sidebar" onClick={() => setIsSidebarOpen(!isSidebarOpen)}>
        {isSidebarOpen ? '<' : '>'}
      </div>
      <main>
        {Array.from({ length: 24 }).map((_, key) => (
          <div className="box" key={key}>{key + 1}</div>
        ))}
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />)
```

```css
body { 
  margin: 0;
}
.App {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 'header header' auto 'sidebar main' 1fr / 3rem 1fr;
  transition: grid-template-columns .35s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .3, 1);
}
.App.sidebar-open {
  grid-template-columns: 16rem 1fr;
}
.App > * {
  padding: 1rem;
}
header {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  grid-area: header;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
  justify-content: center;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  height: min-content;
}
.box {
  aspect-ratio: 1/0.7;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Again, change `150px` to whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Hi, @tao, thanks for the answer! I'll try later today what you suggested! One thing I noticed is that when the drawer is opened, the X axis overflows, which seems odd. Have you experienced that?

Comment: That sounds like a different problem and should probably be asked separately. If you want me to have a look, consider providing a *runnable* [mcve]. Use codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: Sorry, I think it was my browser! It kinda works, but I'm not sure it's the same behavior as YT. For instance, using MUI I am able to choose how many cards per row I can have. Is is possible to have something similar? The problem is, as the screen grows, the cards do not grow to fill the remaining size (or until the next breakpoint), this addind a new one in the specifig row. Hope I was clear enough. And thank you so much

Comment: To me, there is a very obvious contradiction between specifying how many cards (or columns) the container should have and allowing it to get filled with as many columns of a particular minimal width it can fit in the available width. From your comment I understand this contradiction is not as obvious to you as it is to me. If you need help implementing `auto-fill` in MUI, you'll have to provide a *runnable* [mcve] (in codesandbox.io or similar) with what you currently have.

Comment: And no, you're not clear enough. I don't understand what you mean by *"I'm not sure it's the same behavior as YT"*, nor by *"it kinda works"*. You need to be more specific. Is any of the provided snippets working as expected?